# Detect if an activity is running from a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, sdk

So I am building an app which is running on a single activity and multiple fragments.

One of the feature is using a 3rd party application where I am sending an event to their servers using their SDK and in response I am supposed to get an intent which trigger an animation. The 3rd parties doesn't generate issue if the 3rd parties activities is not triggered.

In my case, I have the intent-filter as below:

```
   <activity
            android:name="sdk.abc.io.activities.GateActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="abc-keyxxx" />
            </intent-filter>
```

So, when my fragment A is loaded, it submit an event to the abc server using the sdk. The ABC server is supposed to send back an intent and launch the `GateActivity`.

In some cases, the intent is not received and I get stuck in my Fragment A.

My fragment is running a code as below:

```
   override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if(viewModel.isAbcHasBeenStarted()) {
            mainViewModel.hideProgress()
            goToNextPage()
        } else {
            mainViewModel.showProgress
            viewModel.startAbcFlow()
        }
    }
```

This working fine in case the Abc activity is triggered because when I am leaving the activity Abc, the lifecycle let me act as I was planning. If the Abc activity doesn't start (no intent received), I stay for ever in the Fragment A.

I was hoping to find a way to check in the `onResume` of my Fragment A if the Abc activity is running let's say 2sec after the request and if not, I am just triggering the navigation from the Fragment A to any view I need.

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if(viewModel.isAbcHasBeenStarted()) {
            mainViewModel.hideProgress()
            goToNextPage()
        } else {
            mainViewModel.showProgress
            viewModel.startAbcFlow()
            Handler().postDelayed({
                isActivityStarted()
            }, 3000)
        }
    }

   fun isActivityStarted() {
      //check if sdk.abc.io.activities.GateActivity is started
}
```

I have no clue how to properly check in the `sdk.abc.io.activities.GateActivity` is running or started in order to not get stuck in my Fragment

Any idea?

Comment: How are you expecting result from the SDK ? Are you using `ActivityresultAPI` or the old version `startActivityForResult`? Your workflow seems little bit messed up . When you  submit  event to the abc server using the sdk How are you getting the result back ?

Comment: So this is entirely handle by the SDK, I do not have much information provided by the 3rd parties. My assumptions is that the 3rd parties send back maybe a url and the SDK is loading the url into a webview. But I also feel that it's messed up because the SDK never handle error cases, animation are triggered by event but event are not confirmed. This is mainly way, I have to check if the activity is started